# Draw route in google map with react

Tags: reactjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am new in react and I am developing a delivery system app, and I am facing some challenges to show the route of a particular goods from point A to point B.

here's what I have done

Code to fetch the coordinates from API

```
const fetchData = () => {
    axios
        .post(config.context_url + "/order/getById", {orderID: id})
        .then(response => {           
            origin.push({lat: response.data.data.fromX, lng: response.data.data.fromY});
            destination.push({lat: response.data.data.toX, lng: response.data.data.toY});

        })
   
}

return (
    
    <MainCard title={title}>                           
        <div>
            <MapRoute origin={origin} destination={destination}/> // Calling the map with props origin and destination
        </div>
     </MainCard>
   )
```

Map.js file

```
import React from 'react'
import GoogleMapReact from "google-map-react";


const MapRoute = (props) => {
    const origin = props.origin;
    const destination = props.destination;


    const currentLocation = {
        lat: 40.756795,
        lng: -73.954298
    }
   
    const apiIsLoaded = (map) => {

        const directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
        const directionsRenderer = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
        
        directionsRenderer.setMap(map);

    
        console.log("PICKUP", origin, "DROPOFF", destination) // I can see in the console the origin and destination
        
        directionsService.route({
            origin: origin,
            destination: destination,
            travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
        }, (result, status) => {
            if (status === google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                directionsRenderer.setDirections(result);
            } else {
                console.error(`error fetching directions ${result}`);
            }
        });       
    };

    return (
        <>
            <div>
                <div
                    style={{
                    height: "400px",
                    width: "100%",
                    marginBottom: "20px"
                }}>
                    <GoogleMapReact
                    options={{
                        zoomControl: false,
                        fullscreenControl: false,
                        mapTypeControl: false,
                        streetViewControl: false
                    }}
                        bootstrapURLKeys={{
                        key: "API_KEY"
                    }}
                        defaultCenter={{
                        lat: 40.756795,
                        lng: -73.954298
                    }}
                        defaultZoom={10}
                        center={currentLocation}
                        yesIWantToUseGoogleMapApiInternals
                        onGoogleApiLoaded={({map, maps}) => apiIsLoaded(map, maps)}/>
                </div>
            </div>        
        </>
    )
}

export default MapRoute
```

The error the I got
[image]

But when I put static lat and lng I got no error at all. See the image bellow
[image]

Comment: I don't see any state hooks being implemented here. And you can you please provide more details as to where you got the props.origin?